# How to optimize the runtime for datatable to collection transformation?

Tags: c#, performance, collections, loops

I have a database to which i have to connect through odbc.

The data fetch takes app. 2 minutes. and the resulting DataTable has 350000 records.

I am trying to transform the data table into this object graph. The resultset has no primary key, the primary key is specified through the view from which i fetch data.

```
public class PriceCurve
{
    public PriceCurve(DataTable dt)
    {
        this.Id = int.Parse(dt.AsEnumerable().First()["ID"].ToString());
        this.Prices = new List<Price>();
        GetPrices(dt);
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public IList<Price> Prices { get; set; }

    private void GetPrices(DataTable dt)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            switch (this.GetPriceProviderType(column)) // parses ColumnName to Enum
            {
                case Price.PriceProvider.A:
                    {
                        this.Prices.Add(new Price(Price.PriceProvider.A, dt.AsEnumerable()));
                    }

                    break;
                case Price.PriceProvider.B:
                    {
                        this.Prices.Add(new Price(Price.PriceProvider.B, dt.AsEnumerable()));
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

    public class Price
    {
        public enum PriceProvider
        {
            A, B
        }

        public Price(PriceProvider type, IEnumerable<DataRow> dt)
        {
            this.Type = type;
            this.TradingDates = new List<TradingDate>();
            this.GetTradingDates(type, dt);
        }

        public IList<TradingDate> TradingDates { get; set; }
        public PriceProvider Type { get; set; }

        private void GetTradingDates(PriceProvider type, IEnumerable<DataRow> dt)
        {
            var data = dt.Select(column => column["TRADING_DATE"]).Distinct();

            foreach (var date in data)
            {
                this.TradingDates.Add(new TradingDate(date.ToString(), type, dt));
            }
        }

        public class TradingDate
        {
            public TradingDate(string id, PriceProvider type, IEnumerable<DataRow> dt)
            {
                this.Id = id;
                this.DeliveryPeriodValues = new Dictionary<int, double?>();
                this.GetDeliveryPeriodValues(type, dt);
            }

            public string Id { get; set; }
            public IDictionary<int, double?> DeliveryPeriodValues { get; set; }

            private void GetDeliveryPeriodValues(PriceProvider type, IEnumerable<DataRow> dt)
            {

                foreach (var row in dt.Where(column => column["TRADING_DATE"].ToString() == this.Name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.DeliveryPeriodValues.Add(
                            int.Parse(row["DELIVERY_PERIOD"].ToString()),
                            double.Parse(row[Enum.GetName(typeof(Price.PriceProvider), type)].ToString()));
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        this.DeliveryPeriodValues.Add(
                            int.Parse(row["DELIVERY_PERIOD"].ToString()),
                            null);
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

i create one object, which contains a list with two objects. Each of these two objects contains a list with 1000 objects. Each of these 1000 objects contains a dictionary with 350 pairs.

It either crashes visual studio 2010 during debug, fails because of OutOfMemory or takes minutes (unacceptable) to execute.

What is the best approach to this problem. i am new to c# and do not know how to optimize the looping through this huge data or my object graph. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It either crashes visual studio 2010 during debug, fails because of OutOfMemory or takes minutes 
>   (unacceptable) to execute.

YOu made me laugh. Really.

- 350.000 nodes is challenging on a 32 bit machine with .NET. Add some overhead and you are dead. Use objects, not adata table which is VERY memory destroying.
- takes minutes is pretty much your decision / programming. Use a list of objects, not a data table. Use a profiler. DOnt make beginner mistakesl ike:

> var data = dt.Select(column => column["TRADING_DATE"]).Distinct();

No need for that, deal with doubles later inthe code. Distinct is expensive. Profile it.

> foreach (var row in dt.Where(column => column["TRADING_DATE"].ToString() == this.Name))

That is 350.000 row lookups by name to get the index of the column, compared by a lot of tostring.

Get a profiler and find out where you exactly spend your time. Get please rid of the table and use objects - DataTable is a memory hog and SLOW compared to a list of objects. And yes, it will take minutes. Main reasons:

- Your programming. Not a shame. Just learn, Go objets / structs NOW.
- ODBC. Takes time to just load the data, especially as you dont process swhile loading (DataReader) but wait for allto ahve loaded, and ODBC is NOT fast. 350.000 rows, good network, direct SQL Server is maybe 30 seconds - same machine less.

Comment: so i should basically take the data reader and work directly with each object[] which is returned by reader.GetNames(new object[])

Comment: No, that is an array, not adata transfer object. You should immediately transfer them into real objets. You know, the type with variables, properties.

Comment: Yeah i have heard of this thingys ;).
so the best approach would be something like { var neededCol = reader.GetOrdinal("TRADING_DATE"); var myObj = new PriceCurve(); while (reader.Read()) { myObj.MyProperty = reader.GetValue(neededCol);}}

Comment: Pretty much. This takes the GetOrdinal out of the loop (yes, it is not for free - it is a hashtable lookup) and then you work with small efficient objects. Then DUMP ODBC - either use OLEDB or a natce driver. The later is there for pretty much every major database. And if you still nmeed more memory go to 64 bit OS ;)

Comment: I think a huge bottleneck is your use of data tables. They are heavy, and inefficient..

Start over. rewrite with a concrete class representing each record in you table(s). Use DataReaders to get the data of each row, and convert it to an instance of that class. Write a method that returns a List of that class, to represent the whole table, or the results of your queries..

@TomTom is right! Page the results. Use a query that can get x number of items starting at item y. (Paging in SQL: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx)